# Stopping Deleting/renaming on a Window Virtual Disk

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vhd

I have created a Windows VHD image files using the C/C++ API, is there a way so that I can intercept right-click context menu items such as 'cut', 'copy' and 'delete' ?

The application is being written on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2014 Pro.

Comment: How about proper ACLs?

Comment: @deviantfan I don't want a user to be able to right-click and change the permission to read-write.... Can an ACL be applied that will stop that, regardless if an administrator etc?

Comment: No, that isn´t possible. But I have three reasons against your plan: a) I can´t imagine why something like this would make sense. I´m sure there is a cleaner solution. Tell us why do you want to do this. b) I´m considering this as malware, that means I would never let this run on any computer I manage. If you don´t want to piss off your users... c) Even with such a hack, you can´t prevent anything. Linux...

Comment: @deviantfan This isn't malware, what I am actually trying to do is build a virtual disk that can pull changes from a system via secure socket.  Updates to disk occur as new data is added/modified or deleted, effectively a rudimentary cm tool.

Comment: `This isn't malware` ... but it behaves like one. Don´t prevent the user from doing normal things. What you´re looking for is a own virtual disk driver. And there´s still the problem to tell the virtualization software that something changed... (of course you could run the driver inside the VM)